# Find a solution for $y$ in a nonlinear second order differential equation (missing x).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

**Q.** $y''+yy' = 0$. Find a solution satisfying each of the following sets of initial conditions. If your computer says there is no such solution, don't believe it do it by hand.

$(a)\quad y(0) = 5,\ y'(0) = 0\\
(b)\quad y(0) = 2,\ y'(0) = -2\\
(c) \quad y(0) = 1,\ y'(0) = -1\\
(d)\quad y(0) = 0,\ y'(0) = 2$

---

I can't quite get the correct answer. What I get is as follows:

$$y^{\prime\prime} + yy^\prime = 0 \tag1$$

$$\frac{dy^\prime}{dy} + y = 0 \tag2$$

$$y^\prime + \frac12y^2 = \text{const.} \tag3$$

But then I get confused about what to do with the initial conditions and how it relates with the $\text{const.}$ I get in $(3)$. Is my constant a function of $y$ or $x$? Or is it a function of both? Without minding the initial conditions and ignoring constants during integration, I get

$$y = \frac2x \tag4$$

Which is exactly what Boas tells me not to believe...

Comment: Your solution attempt is perfectly fine, however the constants **really do matter**. You can see my answer for a start, if you want further detail I can edit and add some more steps :)

Comment: Note that (3) is a Bernoulli ODE and has well-known solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

$${y'' + yy' = 0}$$

is equivalent to

$${\frac{d}{dx}[y'] + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}[(y)^2]=0}$$

Rearranging and integrating:

$${\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}[y'] = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}[(y)^2]}$$

$${\Rightarrow y' = -\frac{1}{2}(y)^2 + c_1}$$

As you said. Although you got here by chain rule. You said

$${y'' = \frac{dy'}{dx} = \frac{dy'}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}}$$

And so the ODE cancels to

$${\frac{dy'}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} + y\frac{dy}{dx}=0}$$

And obviously cancelling the ${y'}$ (provided ${y'\neq 0}$) gives

$${\frac{dy'}{dy} + y = 0}$$

Then integrating both sides with respect to $y$, you get the same thing. Both are completely valid!

Anyways, this is just a separable ODE. Note

$${\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = c_1-\frac{1}{2}y^2}$$

$${\Rightarrow \frac{1}{c_1-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dy = dx}$$

**EDIT**: This is the stage that is incorrect if ${y'(0)=0}$ so ${c_1-\frac{1}{2}y^2(0)=0}$. You are dividing through by $0$ at this stage, so every step after this becomes invalid. When doing divisions like this of general expressions - you should technically always check to make sure you aren't dividing by a potential $0$. In this case - it only happens if ${y'(0)=0}$. Sorry - I should have stated this previously :)

Anyways, provided **we haven't just divided by $0$**:

$${\Rightarrow\int \frac{1}{c_1-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dy = x + c_2}$$

Now we are left to integrate

$${\int\frac{1}{c_1-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dy}$$

You should obviously firstly take the case ${c_1=0}$ (this will you give you a nice trivial solution, so I will leave this to you). Otherwise, if ${c_1>0}$, after factoring

$${=\int\frac{1}{c_1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2c_1}y^2}dy=\int\frac{1}{c_1}\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c_1}}y\right)^2}dy}$$

And to integrate this, you should do a substitution of ${u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c_1}}y}$ and use partial fractions. You then must take the case ${c_1<0}$. I won't write out the steps again, but in this case you cannot use the trick ${\sqrt{c_1}^2 = c_1}$ since the square root will be imaginary and things get complicated. The answer will be in terms of ${\tan}$ in this case.

The bottom line is - you really cannot ignore the constants, since the answer changes depending on what that constant is. Obviously for the initial conditions, you do not know the sign of ${c_1}$, so what do you do? Well, going back to

$${y' + \frac{1}{2}y^2 = c_1}$$

Plugging in ${x=0}$ will of course give you the value of ${c_1}$, and so you will know which anti-derivative to take based on this :)

Upon request, I could add more steps (for example, I could show how to continue to compute the anti-derivative and show the answer to the first part), but first - can you try taking it from here?

Comment: With the initial conditions $y(0) = 5$ and $y^\prime(0) = 0$ (therefore $c_1 = 25/2$), what I got was as follow: $$\frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac12\left(25 - y^2\right)$$ $$\int\frac{dy}{5+y} + \int\frac{dy}{5-y} = 5x + \ln{c_2}$$ $$\ln{\left|\frac{5+y}{5-y}\right|} = c_2e^{5x}$$ Then I can't find the value of $c_2$ because by setting $y(0) = 5$, the denominator on the left-hand side would be $0$.

Comment: @J.Herrera : You should have seen this earlier as a division-by-zero problem. Thus first analyze the stationary, constant solutions.

Comment: I kind of see now that for the first case, $y \equiv 5$, but then that was only because it was a trivial case, and yet I can't really come up with a  *written* proof for such an answer. Any tips?

Comment: Following your answer as a guide, I got the solution for (b) which is $$y = \frac2{x+1}$$ But going back to (a), how do I approach the problem knowing that $y^\prime = 0$? I get that it’s possible, shown [here in example 2](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html), but how do you get the non-constant solution (if there is)?

Comment: I also did manage to get (c), $$y = \tan\left(\frac\pi4 - \frac x2\right) \text{,}$$ and (d), $$y = \frac{2\left(e^{2x} - 1\right)}{e^{2x} + 1} \text{.}$$ But I’m still not so confident with what you said about dividing by zero, and I’m not so sure what to do when dealing with such a case.

Answer (score 2):

You could also see
$$
y'+\frac12y^2=c=y'(0)+\frac12y(0)^2
$$
as Riccati equation and set $y=\frac{2u'}{u}$ to get
$$
u''=\frac12cu, ~~ u(0)=2, ~ u'(0)=y(0)
$$
which has well-known solutions.

Comment: How did you infer that $y = 2u^\prime/u$? I'm unfamiliar with the Riccati equation.

Comment: It is just a substitution that works. In $y'+py^2=q$ one can always substitute $y=\frac{u'}{pu}$ to get the quadratic terms to cancel.